# Calculate wash sales deferred loss unequal shares

Tags: united-states, wash-sale

How do you calculate the deferred loss from the following:

| symbol | Buy & Sell date | QT | Proceeds | Cost | Gain/Loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 2/20/21 | 50 | 300.5 | 320.5 | -20 |
| XYZ | 2/20/21 | 30 | 165.8 | 196.8 | -31 |
| XYZ | 2/20/21 | 3 | 14.75 | 17.75 | -3 |

Each quantity of shares was bought and sold the same day.

Example:
50 shares bought 2/20/21, 50 shares sold 2/20/21.

Comment: You label a column as Buy/Sell date but which are the purchases and which are the sales? Are there any missing rows?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Each purchase was bought and sold the same day.

Answer (score 1):

At the start of the day, you had a pile of cash and no shares. At the end of the day you had a pile of cash and no shares. Just compare the piles and that is either your gains or your losses. Based on your numbers you lost $54.

Unless you buy more shares within the next 30 days, or you bought shares in the previous 30 days, the fact that you closed all the positions means there is no wash sale consideration.

Comment: Technically, the second and third purchases triggered wash sale violations which were remediated when the these substantially identical shares were liquidated.  In terms of taxation, it makes no difference since there is no carry forward deferred loss.